# Teamcity fails to publish artifacts and stop builds

Tags: sockets, networking, teamcity, port, teamcity-7.1

I'm having an issue with TeamCity that is proving very difficult to solve for a number of reasons. I've looked around and not found any useful answers so far.

We have a teamcity server running on port 8080 with two agents connecting to it on ports 9090 and 9091 respectively. The agents register successfully and can accept new builds just fine. When the build is complete, tests have passed and the logs state "Sending artifacts" things stop and the artifacts never reach the server. Having left this sit overnight I make requests to stop the build which fail.

We have recently switched to a new firewall but things have been working after setting the required port rules for 8080, 9090 and 9091. No changes have been made since we got things working but now things do not work.

To the logs...
The server is aware of the failure as I can see logs in several places stating:

> `jetbrains.buildServer.SERVER - Failed to upload artifact, due to error: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Read timed out`

The agent also has logs stating a similar reason:

> `jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Failed to publish artifacts because of error: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error, will try again.`

During all this the firewall logs show that all traffic on the expected ports is being allowed through. What is odd though are some logs that look like this:

> `2016-04-01 10:45:00 Deny [sourceIp] [targetIP] 49426/tcp 8080 49426 0-External Firebox tcp syn checking failed (expecting SYN packet for new TCP connection, but received ACK, FIN, or RST instead). 558 113 (Internal Policy)  proc_id="firewall" rc="101" msg_id="3000-0148" tcp_info="offset 5 A 478076245 win 258"`

Examining port 49426 on the agent shows that it was being used by java.exe. Now I'm assuming this might have something to do with TeamCity as it runs in the JVM. The next step was to scour every bit of config I can find to figure out where this port number comes from. After a while the agent decided to retry and the port changed. It looks to me that java is just using whatever port it wants (as if unassigned in code) so could there be something missing in the agent config instructing it which port to use for artifact uploads?

I did read somewhere that perhaps the server or the firewall doesn't like requests or file uploads that exceed a certain size (the largest file is 81 meg) but we found nothing to suggest there was such a rule in place.

The Teamcity version is old (v7.1.1) but we are currently unable to upgrade (I am waiting on approval to use a newer, bigger server due to hard disk space issues).

**UPDATE**
We very briefly opened up a bit of the firewall to see if it was the cause of the issues to no avail. At this point I'm not convinced the firewall is the problem.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 2**
I've ended up setting up a whole new build server and things work just fine there. The new server has the latest TeamCity version but the agents are the same machines and artifact uploads appear to work just fine. This isn't really a solution to the question but at least I have a working setup now.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the agent is too slow to start sending data for whatever reason. [This workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-19951/Tomcat-can-close-connection-by-timeout-if-agent-publishes-artifacts-too-slow#focus=Comments-27-290062.0-0) by Jetbrains employee Pavel Sher might help:

Increase the `connectionTimeout` value in the `server.xml` file

```
    <Connector port="8111" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8543"                
               enableLookup="false"
               useBodyEncodingForURI="true">
```

To 20000 to 60000 or even more.